# Apps Script (Ошибка Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. Creator @ Код.gs:10)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Написал скрипт для автоматизированого создания и заполнения в файле нужних полей, но есть данная ошибка `Ошибка Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. Creator  @ Код.gs:10`

Посмотрите пожалуйста на код, подскажите где я ошибся.

```
function Creator() {

const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1DhHBAd3ssYMgbbxJatK6_URxBPdoPk2K");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16keE-_Dm0gglO42Lw0IphiPHYK-_TFXH");
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ZsmW9UPNaqgjt8kFh3y9h8tdBLAtj7gC");
var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var l=list.getLastRow();
for (var i=2; i <= l; i++) {
const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
const body = tempDocFile.getBody(); 
var a1 = list.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
var a2 = list.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
body.replaceText("{firstname}", a1);
body.replaceText("{lastname}", a2);
tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
const pdfFile = tempDocFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfFile).setName(a1);
tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentsApp` общается не с самым быстрым сервисом. Он часто не находит новые файлы. Попробуйте вот так

```js
    const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
    const tempId = tempFile.getId();
    // Utilities.sleep(300);
    const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempId);
```

Если не получится, попробуйте убрать из комментариев третью строку и поправить время ожидания.